# Angular: Enable button asynchronously

Tags: html, angular

I am fetching data in my angular app from a REST API. I want to enable the button of the search once the user logs in. I have added auth.service.ts which I am importing in my search navbar component. But, the button doesn't get enabled once the user logs in. The data is asynchronous so, it either remains disabled or enabled. I can't figure it out.
Here's my code:

> navbar.component.ts

```
allowSearch: boolean = false;

buttonEnable() // this should get called every time change is detected in the input
  {
    if(this.authService.isAuthenticated())
    {
      this.allowSearch = true;
    }
  }
```

> navbar.component.html

```
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control" (change) = "buttonEnable()" placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)] = 
"searchElement" name = "searchElement"
        style = "background-color: #faf9f9" id = "searchElement" >

<div class="input-group-append" style = "background-color: #faf9f9">
        <button  type="button" name="button" type = "submit" [disabled] = "!allowSearch" (click) = 
        "openModal2(); onSearch(searchElement)"><i class="nc-icon nc-zoom-split"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: When you call the `buttonEnable()`, what is the value of `this.authService.isAuthenticated()` ? Does the `this.authService.isAuthenticated()` return you correctly?

Comment: false as the user hasn't logged in and is shown a sign in page.

Comment: Then it will not able to become `this.allowSearch` = true, since it will never hit the condition you set. Try to check how the `this.authService.isAuthenticated()` works and able to convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call to authService outside of navBar, you can get it if your service has, futhermore a method to login, a Subject. Else simply change the variable **in** the subscribe function.

e.g. using Subject:

```
LoginService(){
   isLoggin:Subject<boolean>=new Subject<boolean>()
   
   loggin(data){
     this.httpClient.get(....).pipe(
       tap(res=>{
         if (.....)
           this.isLoggin.next(true)
        })
     )
    }

    loggout(){
     this.httpClient.get(....).pipe(
       tap(_=>{
           this.isLoggin.next(false)
        })
     )
    }

}
```

Your nav-bar-component inject in constructor the loginService -make it public-

```
constructor(public loginService:LoginService){}
```

And your .html can be simple

```
<button [disabled]="!(loginService.isLoggin|async)">I'm login</button>
```

(*)tap not change the response, but executed when "someone" subscribe to our observable.

Comment: @Package.JSON, I just updated the answer using "pipe(tap)" to "capture the answer and, when some subscribe return true or false. I hope that makes more clear my original answer

Answer (score 0):

Here 'this.allowSearch' is getting initialized in buttonEnable(). Once you login to the application, You should call the 'buttonEnable()' method.

Same wise, When ever you logout from app, you should invoke the 'buttonEnable()' method.

So 'allowSearch' value will be updated.

Instead of this approach, you should have RXJS observables. have 'allowSearch' property in RXJS store and update based on login and logout actions.

Your component should subscribe for 'allowSearch' from store and update the 'allowSearch' component property.